# How can I hide the red line in timevis?

Tags: r, timeline

I'm working with a timeline using [timevis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timevis/index.html) but I don't know how to hide the red line that marks the current date.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Your question needs to be more specific, it would help to give a link to a screenshot of the problem...but most importantly, a simple piece of code--the shortest program you can think of--which can let others reproduce the effect you want to get rid of on their own installations.  Note the "edit" button so you can add more detail to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The red line indicates the current time on the timeline. However, once you add data to the timeline, the red line is no longer there. Nonetheless, a line must exist that points to the current time on the timeline.

**From the docs `?timevis`:**

```
# most basic
timevis()
```

[image]

```
# minimal data
timevis(
data.frame(id = 1:2,
         content = c("one", "two"),
         start = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-12"))
)
```

[image]

See [timevis - Create interactive timeline visualizations in R: Advanced ecamples](https://github.com/daattali/timevis#slightly-more-advanced-examples) **to customize the look of the timeline.**

> By default, a timeline will show the current date as a red vertical
>   line and will have zoom in/out buttons. You can supply many
>   customization options to timevis() in order to get it just right (see
>   ?timevis() for details).

See the files in the `www` folder of this repo as a guide to customization. https://github.com/daattali/timevis/tree/master/inst/example/www

Comment: The reason it doesn't show up in your example is because the date range you selected don't include the current time (27-07-2017). See the example from @Zuti

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to do this: using the options inside timevis

```
df<- data.frame(
  id      = 1:4,
  content = c("Item one", "Item two",
              "Ranged item", "Item four"),
  start   = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-11",
              "2016-01-20", "2016-02-14 15:00:00"),
  end     = c(NA, NA, "2016-02-04", NA),
  editable = TRUE
)
timevis(df, options = list( showCurrentTime = FALSE))
```